# Recognizing a 3D graph with 2 variables

Tags: 3d, mathematical-modeling

just wondering if anyone recognizes a general formula with 2 variables for the graphs attached. The range is $x \in [0,3]$ and $H \in (0,0.5)$. You don't have to suggest an exact formula for the graph, just a general one will do. I think I can do the scaling myself.

I have attached 6 graphs below. Notice the "title" of the graph with $H$ on top and the x axis of the graph going from $[0,3]$. I am having trouble identifying even for the 1 variable graph for $H=0.001$. Any suggestion?

[image: H is 0.001][image: H is 0.1] [image: H is 0.2][image: H is 0.3][image: H is 0.4][image: H is 0.4999]